# What is the best way to test new consensus protocol?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, consensus, source-code

I wanted to test a new [consensus protocol](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08092.pdf). However, the [bitcoin core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) is a large codebase (>100k lines). Is there any small codebase which is designed to test new consensus protocols and includes only essential features of a cryptocurrency?

Goal: Run a testnet with a few AWS-EC2 instances across the world for payments using UTXO model.

Comment: What is the goal or scope of your test? What are the key differences between it and bitcoin (or other cryptocurrencies) that you hope to test?

Comment: @chytrik: I have updated the question. I just want to change the consensus protocol of Bitcoin to support high throughput for payments.